# Does the mathematical meaning of "up to" relate to the ordinary English meanings?

Tags: terminology

Does "up to" defined by [Pete L. Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/430557) or 
[Tobias Kildetoft](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1353549) relate to the 2020 English meanings from [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/219798)?

If not, why did mathematicians utilize "up to"?

[image]

Comment: why the downvotes???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the most common meaning of "up to" in mathematical literature is "when you do not distinguish the objects that share some property". For example, the following statement

> There are 2 groups of order 4, *up to isomorphism*.

means that when we do not distinguish isomorphic groups, there are only 2 groups of order 4 ($\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$).

Comment: And the connection with the everyday meaning is fairly clear if we expand the sentence like this: *Up to (i.e., until) the point at which we start distinguishing isomorphic groups there are two groups of order $4$.*

Comment: @BrianM.Scott well noted.